# Bluetooth reception on arduino

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have created an android application which sends a value between 0 and 20 like this :

```
    public void write(byte[] msg) {
        cnt++;
        Log.v("CNT", Integer.toString(cnt));
        try {
            for(byte b : msg)
            {
                Log.v("Buffer", Byte.toString(b));
            }
            mmOutStream.write(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) { Log.e("ConnectedThread","Send Error",e); }
    }
```

My arduino code is the following :

```
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(2,8);


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Bluetooth Start!");

}

void loop()
{
  char inDat;
  char outDat;
  if(bluetooth.available())
  {
    inDat = bluetooth.read();
    Serial.println(inDat);
  }
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    outDat = Serial.read();
    bluetooth.write(outDat);
  }
}
```

I was hoping to get numbers between 0 and 20 on the serial console but i only get "ÿ"

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get this `ÿ` stuff when in the serial monitor I put a different baudrate than the Arduino board is using. May be this?
Also (and this is just a tip), you should use `Serial.write(inDat)` instead of `Serial.println(inDat)`, because `println` function adds `'\n'` at the end.